# Image Segmentation with a challenging background

Tags: python, scikit-learn, image-processing, image-segmentation

[cross-posted from datascience, as no answers received]

I'm working on an animal classification problem, with the data extracted from a video feed. The recording was made in a pen, so the problem is quite challenging with a dark background and many shadows: [image]

Initially I tried scikit-image, but then someone helped me with an advanced tool called crf-rnn (http://crfasrnn.torr.vision/) that does a great job segmenting and labelling objects in an image. I did the following:

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Segmenter(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED)
IMAGE_FILE = '0045_crop2.png'
input_image = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_FILE)
from PIL import Image as PILImage
image = PILImage.fromarray(np.uint8(input_image))
image = np.array(image)
mean_vec = [np.mean(image[:,:,vals]) for vals in range(image.shape[2])]
im = image[:, :, ::-1]
im = im - reshaped_mean_vec
cur_h, cur_w, cur_c = im.shape
pad_h = 750 - cur_h
pad_w = 750 - cur_w
print(pad_h, pad_w, "999")
im = np.pad(im, pad_width=((0, max(pad_h,0)), (0, max(pad_w,0)), (0, 0)), mode = 'constant', constant_values = 255)
segmentation = net.predict([im])
segmentation2 = segmentation[0:cur_h, 0:cur_w]
```

The resulting image segmentation is rather poor (although two cows are recognized correctly):
[image]

I use a trained crf-rnn (MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED), which works well for other problems, but this one is harder. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to pre-process this sort of image to extract the shape of most cows.

Comment: Since you have a video feed, can't you capitalize on the wealth of additional data it offers?  For instance, you ought to be able to recover an image of all or most of the background (at that particular time of day) and use that to identify the background pixels with good accuracy.

Comment: OK, any suggestions on how to approach background extraction?

Comment: Hi @Alex, I got "'module' object has no attribute 'Segmenter'" this error while using net = caffe.Segmenter(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED). I have successfully installed pycaffe and tested as well. For eg: If I use net = caffe.Net('conv.prototxt', caffe.TEST), it works properly. Do you know the reason?

Comment: it's usually pythonpath for caffe - make sure it is the one that has Segmenter class (Crf-rnn), not the one in site-packages

Comment: Cross-posted: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/10809/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: [A stored google search on background identification](https://www.google.com/search?q=background+extraction+from+videos&oq=background+extraction+from+videos&aqs=chrome..69i57.11143j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)